# Browser-based REST api authentication

Tags: rest, oauth, amazon-web-services, restful-authentication

I'm working on a REST webservice, and in particular authentication methods for browser-based requests. (using JsonP  or Cross-domain XHR requests/XDomainRequest).

I've done some research in OAuth, and also Amazon's AWS. The big drawbacks of both is that I need to do either of the following:

- Store secret tokens in the browser
- Let a server-side script handle the signing. Basically I'd first to a request to a server of mine to get a specific pre-signed javascript request, which I'll use to connect to the real REST server.

What are some other options or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the only true answer here is proxying through a server, using sessions/cookies to authenticate and of course use SSL. Sorry for answering my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, jsonp call-authentication is tough, because the browser-client needs to know the shared secret.

An option would be to make the end-point anonymous (no authentication necessary). This comes with other security wholes (server is open for attacks, anyone can call it). But you could handle this by either only exposing very limited resource and/or using rate-limiting. With rate-limiting only a certain number of calls are allowed by one client in a certain range of time. It works by identifying the client (e.g. by source-ips or other client footprints).

I once experimented with one-time tokens, but they all somewhat failed because you have the problem of getting the token itself and protecting multiple retrievals of the token by bots (which comes again to the need of rate-limiting).

Comment: sorry... late evening typing/spelling, this morning would have used the term vulnerability ;)

Comment: I'm considering going with a limited-time multi request token.. :S

Comment: when you're finished, would be cool to know your implementation

Answer (score 0):

I havent tried this myself but you can try the following..(I am pretty sure i will get some feedback)

On the server side, generate a timestamp. Using HMAC-SHA256 an generate a key for that time stamp using a password and send the generated key and time stamp in the html.

When you make the AJAX call to the web service(assuming it is a different server) send the key and the time stamp along with the request. Check if timestamp is within a 5-15 minutes..
if it is do do the HMAC-SHA256 with the same password and key if the key generated is same.
Also on the client side you will have to check if your timestamp is still valid before making the call..

You can generate the key using the following url..
http://buchananweb.co.uk/security01.aspx